# Registering a function that connects the app to mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, fastify

There's a function for connecting my app to mongoose/mongodb that I pass as argument in `fastify.register()`. It throws an error that says:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERR_AVVIO_PLUGIN_TIMEOUT:
> plugin did not start in time: mongoose_default. You may have forgotten
> to call 'done' function or to resolve a Promise

Initially, the function looked like this:

```
export default async function (
    fastify: FastifyInstance | never,
    options: { uri: string },
    done: DoneFuncWithErrOrRes,
) {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(options.uri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        });

        console.log('MongoDB connection successful.');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }

    done();
}
```

I realized that `done()` is being executed first before the mongoose connection since `mongoose.connect()` is asynchronous. So I tried putting `done()` inside `setTimeout()`, like so:

```
export default async function (
    fastify: FastifyInstance | never,
    options: { uri: string },
    done: DoneFuncWithErrOrRes,
) {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(options.uri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        });

        console.log('MongoDB connection successful.');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        done();
    }, 0);
}
```

It didn't resolve the issue; the error is still there.

Is there anything wrong with the way I connect mongoose and use `fastify.register()`?

Answer (score 0):

The code must be written in:

- callback style (aka `done`)
- or `async` style

not both since they collide.

If you remove the `done` call all will works

Comment: Problem already solved. I just found out that I have to change my DNS since I'm using MongoDB Atlas. Thanks for the help, btw.